# Конструкции типа «По поводу»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова

> По поводу моих любимых книг() Наверное, моя самая любимая книга – «Война и мир».

Какой знак препинания ставить после конструкции типа «По поводу», начинающей предложение и имеющей вводное значение? Допустима и точка и запятая?

Comment: Это вопрос авторского стиля. Здесь можно и двоеточие поставить.

Comment: Ваше «наверное» с прописной, или так только кажется?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Очень часто в таких случаях завершают конструкцию точкой.

Это неполное предложение, смысл которого ясен: ***По поводу моих любимых книг [хочу сказать следующее].*** Поэтому часто используется его неполный вариант, ставится точка.

Запятая здесь, на мой взгляд, просто невозможна, а вот двоеточие можно объяснить.

***По поводу ... книг: наверное, моя самая любимая книга – «Война и мир».*** - Двоеточие в бессоюзном предложении. Первая часть - неполное предложение, вторая часть дополняет и поясняет первую.

Ср.:  ***По поводу ... книг [скажу]: наверное, моя самая любимая книга – «Война и мир».***